# visual studio code debug panel - how to return "watches" section (unhide it)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I hide the **watches section** from debug panel,
but how can I return it back?

[image]

Comment: Did it ever have one?

Comment: I believe it's Debug->Windows->Watch

Comment: Debug menu does not have Window menu ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the "DEBUG" word/button in the upper left.  That'll give you the option to bring it back.